# Can anyone help me around for login session not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am new to php.

I need to log in with a different user in a project but it's not working.

Once I log-out and go back to the browser, the previous user's window will open.

index.php code

```
<?php

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];

            if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
               $message = "You can't leave empty fields";
            }
            else {

               $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `department` WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

               $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
               if($login_check > 0){ 
                  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                     // Get member ID into a session variable
                     $id = $row["ID"];   

                     $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
                     // Get member username into a session variable
                     $username = $row["username"];   

                     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                     // Update last_log_date field for this member now
                     //mysql_query("UPDATE members SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$id'"); 
                     // Print success message here if all went well then exit the script
                     header("location: division.php?ID=$id"); 
                     exit();
                  } // close while
               } 
                           }
                     }

   ?>
```

division.php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["ID"];
$_SESSION["username"];


if (isset($_SESSION['ID'])) {
   // Put stored session variables into local php variable
    $userid = $_SESSION['ID'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   $id=$_GET['ID'];
}
?>
<?php

$id = $_GET['ID'];
if ($id == "") {
   echo "Missing Data to Run";
   exit();
}

include_once "php/connect.php";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM department WHERE ID='$id' LIMIT 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($count > 1) {
   echo "There is no user with that id here.";
   exit();   
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $id=$row['ID'];
$department = $row["Department"];
$name= $row["name"];
}
?>
```

The session Id and Username are updating but the problem is when I click on the logout button at the top it will redirect to the main index.html. But whenever I click the back button of the browser then it opens the previous user's page that was logged in

It should not do that right ?

```
logout.php code


session_destroy();
header('location:../index.php') ;
```

Comment: Did you do session_start(); before using sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'd set the `$_SESSION` variable to blank on logout.

```
$_SESSION = Array();
```

Then I'd put a check in the top of every page after `session_start()` that checks if the session id is set. If not, redirect to the login page or another page.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) { // redirect to another page else show content
```

On another note, you should seriously look at password encryption methods rather than storing them in human readable format in the database.

Comment: Also, don't just inject your parameters in your query string. That makes it vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

The `session_start();` is missing in index.php file.

Make sure you will add `session_start();` at the top of each file.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good at first glance. Have you tried refreshing the page? My guess is that you're seeing the browser's cached copy and once you reload it will appear logged out as intended.